# Can Android Studio virtual devices recognise external biometric scanners?

Tags: java, biometrics

I am currently writing code for biometric authentication on an Android device, for fingerprint and facial recognition. I was unsure as to whether Android Studio's virtual devices can use external USB scanners plugged into the computer. Or if it is easier to upload the code straight to an Android phone instead and test that way.

Currently, I have not tried anything as I don't want to buy a scanner and camera if they will not function with it.

Comment: The question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow and you're unlikely to get a good answer here. I'm not familiar with your domain but I think I'd ask on [the BioInformatics SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or the [Androids Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @UsmanKhan: your edit has been largely rewritten here too. Most of the things we do want edited (case errors, chatty material and general pleading) were missed in your edit, but you did add in some incorrect formatting. Are you familiar with the discussions on Meta about how to edit correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously developed an Android App that performs Biometric Fingerprint Enrollment and Biometric Fingerprint Authentication using an External USB Fingerprint Scanner and Android Studio.

To be precise, I used a DigitalPersoan 4500 Fingerprint Scanner and Android Studio 3.2.

So here is how it goes, in the past, when I connected the Fingerprint Scanner to the Developer Computer and opened a Virtual Device in Android Studio to run the Biometric App, the Virtual Device would behave as though the Fingerprint Scanner was connected.

It was not possible for the computer to access the Fingerprint Scanner and for the Virtual Device to gain access to it too.

To debug, I would push the Biometric App to a real physical Android Phone and set out to test it.

The challenge here is that you may need a couple of Android Phone devices to test with to be sure that it works on a wider range of devices.

The most important thing I learned was that, if I compiled and build Universal APKs, I maximized the chances of running the Android Biometric App on a large number of devices unlike when independently building arm, arm64, x86 specific platform APKs.

The downside to building a Universal APK is that it will be very large in size than when buidling an App for a particular architecture of Android Phones. So depending on how you plan to distribute your end Biometric Android App, the size of the APK may be a factor to consider before hand.

As for Facial Recognition, I have not developed any solution in that regard but I do not think it would be any different from developing a feature for Fingerprint Authentication and Fingerprint Enrollment in your Android App because all of them are accessing a hardware device that you need to grant rights to your App to access for capturing Images.

Go ahead and buy your Fingerprint Scanner and debug your Application for the Fingerprint Capture in Phone. The rest of the other functions of your App you can do them in the Virtual Device.

An alternative is to have a couple of Fingerprint Images and a Face Images ( *to momentarily skip step of capturing them from Device*)  in your res folder ( hard code for now ) of your Android Project sources to test and debug with in Android Studio but then towards the end after you have ascertained that your main business logic works, remove them and add code to your Android App to anticipate them from Fingerprint Scanner and Phone Camera